# Get signal from PS/2-mouse in C++?

Tags: c++, mouse

Does anyone know how to get the signal from a PS/2-style mouse by using some c++ code?

What I want to do is the following: I took an old mouse for PS/2 port and want to use the light barrier of the middle wheel for some measurement purposes. It would be nice to get the information about any change of the middle wheel, i.e. the light barrier, by using some C/C++ code.

I tried to find some information on the Internet, but I'm a real n00b regarding port programming and didn't find something of help for me.

Comment: Questions that are this close to the hardware are often easier to answer if you include information about your operating system.

Comment: You need to tell what's your operating system, as this is highly OS dependent.

Comment: This is done at the device driver level, you don't want to go there.  Use the WM_MOUSEWHEEL message that's generated when you operate the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The msdn is decent for this topic, although this may give you higher level information than you're looking for and won't be specific to a particular ps2 port, but will be for any mouse connected to the system.  If you want specific information from only the ps/2 port you'll probably have to look at writing your own device driver.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645601%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_The_Mouse_Wheel

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are *high-level* libraries to do this, I think you'll have to look for a system-dependent solution.

What operating system do you wish to target?

On Linux PS/2 mouses (just like any other device) are represented by a virtual file in the `/dev` directory, usually in `/dev/input` (but it depends on what software is managing your devices `/dev`).
You should find out what device corresponds to your PS/2 mouse and just read it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use windows for this, or more accurately windows xp.